# How do we effectively click on a link using Selenium + php_webdriver + Firefox?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was having lots of glitches with my tests using Codeception + WebDriver + Selenium + Firefox, so I decided to remove Codeception from the variables and do some tests directly using php_webdriver, to discover the problem wasn't in Codeception.

I tried to go to a page using 3 different methods:

```
// Click a link
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('inbox-navigation'))->click();

// Directly go to the address via URL
$driver->get('http://testing.mysite.net/#/messages');

// Click via javascript
$driver->executeScript("jQuery('#inbox-navigation').click();");
```

Of course none of them work and, doing it manually in my browser it works fine. The link appear as clicked, the url changes, but the related page (loaded via ajax) never gets loaded.

Here's the full source code I'm using to test this:

```
<?php

require __DIR__."/vendor/autoload.php";

$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, DesiredCapabilities::firefox());

$driver->manage()->window()->setSize(new \WebDriverDimension(1280, 720));

$driver->get('http://testing.mysite.net/');

$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('email'))->sendKeys('john@doe.com');
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('password'))->sendKeys('secret');
$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('sign-in-button'))->click();

$driver->wait(10)->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::id('inbox-navigation')));

$driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('inbox-navigation'))->click();

sleep(15); /// to make sure it wasn't too fast

$driver->takeScreenshot('screen.png');

var_dump($driver->getCurrentURL());
```

And this is the link changed to Inbox:

[image]

Also, manually executing `jQuery('#inbox-navigation').click();` in console also works fine.